# Creating a Wordpress Widget from another theme

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, themes

I'm trying to add the job search functionality found at the top of this website: https://jobify-demos.astoundify.com/classic/ to my own WP theme I am building.

I've identified that this 'Search Hero Strip' is a widget which needs installing into my theme and then I guess I need to create a widetized area in my own theme so I can add this.

I believe this is the widget from the theme:

```
<?php
/**
 * Home: Search Hero
 *
 * @package Jobify
 * @category Widget
 * @since 3.0.0
 */
class Jobify_Widget_Search_Hero extends Jobify_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->widget_description = __( 'Display a "hero" search area.', 'jobify' );
        $this->widget_id          = 'jobify_widget_search_hero';
        $this->widget_cssclass    = 'widget--home-hero-search';
        $this->widget_name        = __( 'Jobify - Page: Search Hero', 'jobify' );
        $this->control_ops        = array(
            'width' => 400
        );
        $this->settings           = array(
            'home widgetized' => array(
                'std' => __( 'Homepage/Widgetized', 'jobify' ),
                'type' => 'widget-area'
            ),
            'height' => array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'std'  => 'medium',
                'label' => __( 'Hero Height', 'jobify' ),
                'options' => array(
                    'small' => __( 'Small', 'jobify' ),
                    'medium' => __( 'Medium', 'jobify' ),
                    'large' => __( 'Large', 'jobify' )
                )
            ),
            'margin' => array(
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'std'  => 1,
                'label' => __( 'Add standard spacing above/below widget', 'jobify' )
            ),
            'text_color' => array(
                'type'  => 'colorpicker',
                'std'   => '#ffffff',
                'label' => __( 'Text Color:', 'jobify' )
            ),
            'title' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'std'   => '',
                'label' => __( 'Title:', 'jobify' )
            ),
            'description' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'std'   => '',
                'label' => __( 'Description:', 'jobify' ),
                'rows'  => 5
            ),
            'image' => array(
                'type'  => 'image',
                'std'   => '',
                'label' => __( 'Background Image:', 'jobify' )
            ),
            'background_position' => array(
                'type'  => 'select',
                'std'   => 'center center',
                'label' => __( 'Image Position:', 'jobify' ),
                'options' => array(
                    'left top' => __( 'Left Top', 'jobify' ),
                    'left center' => __( 'Left Center', 'jobify' ),
                    'left bottom' => __( 'Left Bottom', 'jobify' ),
                    'right top' => __( 'Right Top', 'jobify' ),
                    'right center' => __( 'Right Center', 'jobify' ),
                    'right bottom' => __( 'Right Bottom', 'jobify' ),
                    'center top' => __( 'Center Top', 'jobify' ),
                    'center center' => __( 'Center Center', 'jobify' ),
                    'center bottom' => __( 'Center Bottom', 'jobify' ),
                    'center top' => __( 'Center Top', 'jobify' )
                )
            ),
            'cover_overlay' => array(
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'std'  => 1,
                'label' => __( 'Use transparent overlay', 'jobify' )
            ),
        );

        if ( jobify()->get( 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ) ) {
            $what = array(
                'what' => array(
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'std' => 'job',
                    'label' => __( 'Search:', 'jobify' ),
                    'options' => array(
                        'job' => __( 'Jobs', 'jobify' ),
                        'resume' => __( 'Resumes', 'jobify' )
                    )
                )
            );

            $this->settings = $what + $this->settings;
        }

        parent::__construct();
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        $text_align = isset( $instance[ 'text_align' ] ) ? esc_attr( $instance[ 'text_align' ] ) : 'left';
        $background_position = isset( $instance[ 'background_position' ] ) ? esc_attr( $instance[ 'background_position' ] ) : 'center center';
        $overlay = isset( $instance[ 'cover_overlay' ] ) && 1 == $instance[ 'cover_overlay' ] ? 'has-overlay' : 'no-overlay';
        $margin = isset( $instance[ 'margin' ] ) && 1 == $instance[ 'margin' ] ? true : false;
        $height = isset( $instance[ 'height' ] ) ? esc_attr( $instance[ 'height' ] ) : 'medium';

        if ( ! $margin ) {
            $before_widget = str_replace( 'widget--home ', 'widget--home widget--home--no-margin ', $before_widget );
        }

        $image = isset( $instance[ 'image' ] ) ? esc_url( $instance[ 'image' ] ) : null;
        $content = $this->assemble_content( $instance );

        $what = isset( $instance[ 'what' ] ) ? esc_attr( $instance[ 'what' ] ) : 'job';

        global $is_flat;
        $is_flat = true;

        ob_start();
        ?>

        <?php echo $before_widget; ?>

            <div class="hero-search hero-search--<?php echo esc_attr( $overlay ); ?> hero-search--height-<?php echo esc_attr( $height ); ?>" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $image; ?>); ?>; background-position: <?php echo $background_position; ?>">

            <div class="container">
                <?php echo $content; ?>

                <?php locate_template( array( $what . '-filters-flat.php' ), true, false ); ?>
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php echo $after_widget; ?>

        <?php

        $content = ob_get_clean();

        echo apply_filters( $this->widget_id, $content );
    }

    private function assemble_content( $instance ) {
        $text_color = isset( $instance[ 'text_color' ] ) ? esc_attr( $instance[ 'text_color' ] ) : '#fff';

        $title = isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ? esc_attr( $instance[ 'title' ] ) : '';
        $content = isset( $instance[ 'description' ] ) ? $instance[ 'description' ] : '';

        $output  = '<div class="hero-search__content" style="color:' . $text_color . '">';
        $output .= '<h2 class="hero-search__title" style="color:' . $text_color . '">' . $title . '</h2>';
        $output .= wpautop( $content );
        $output .= '</div>';

        return $output;
    }
}
```

I've tried to add this inside the functions file but it just produces errors.

I know this might come across as basic and im sure im missing somehting important, but im a bit stuck.

I'd either want to do it as a widget or strip out the search form from it and just add it to my home template page - is either possibe?

Comment: That job search widget extends another one called `Jobify_Widget`. You need that one as well.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for that. Do you have any idea the direction I should go in after I find that widget?

Comment: The `Jobify_Widget` class needs to be declared (loaded) before `Jobify_Widget_Search_Hero` so that it can extend it. I believe the errors you were seeing before were partially related to that. Also, there's a chance that the `Jobify_Widget` has its own dependencies so you may need to get those as well.